# how to enable pcmanfm to copy paste in directories that say "permission denied"

Tags: filesystem, permissions

I need to enable pcmanfm (aka file explorer) to copy and paste from all directories for programing purposes. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close all file manager windows and start it again from command line:

```
sudo pcmanfm
```

This will let you do anything `root` could do. Make sure you don't accidentally drang-and-drop `/usr` into `/lib` or something like that: there will be nothing protecting you from such folly.